# Access contents of operand instructions at runtime in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Is it possible to know the value of operands when you run a program in LLVM ?

For the following C code and IR, is it possible to know at runtime the content of argc? Is it possible to know at runtime the memory address of that variable ?

```
if (argc == 1) {
  ....
} else {
  ....
}

%cmp.i = icmp eq i32 %argc, 1
br i1 %cmp.i, label %f.exit, label %if.else.i
```

The worst possibility that I am thinking about is to keep track of each variable from the moment of initialization through to all instructions that modify it.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "runtime". The content of `argc` is `argc` and its address is `&argc` -- in LLVM IR, there might be an `alloca` that you can `load` from. Do you mean the runtime of the compiler (i.e. compile-time)?

Comment: By runtime I wanted to say when the program runs.

Comment: Joining Ismail, I also think you should clarify what you mean by "know at runtime the content of argc". Maybe provide more context about what, precisely, you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't in general. The simplest reason is that the value might not even exist anymore in the final program. You can always figure that it'll work on simple example using the debug info for instance (hey the debugger can do it after all), but most of the time in an optimized program even the debugger will display that a variable has been "optimized away".